# dynamically updating CSS algorithmically instead with hard coded values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to dynamically change CSS values without the need of hardcoding every single value based on input. Below is what I currently have and while it accomplishes what i'd like it to do - I can't help but feel its super hacky and not scalable. Am I way off course with what i'm doing and is there a better way to accomplish changing CSS for an undetermined amount of elements.

For this use case.. I'm incrementing dollar amounts using jquery's animate function and applying CSS zoom to the amount when it reaches certain character lengths.

```
  /**
 * Updates the ticker CSS based on the ticker ID and the total number of digits in the <span></span> including all signs, decimals, and commas.
 * @param  {string} direction - up or down. are we scaling up or are we scaling down
 * @param  {int} id - the ID of the parent div (do not include a hashbang)
 * @param  {int} length - length of the string inside the <span></span> - includes $,.
 */
function updateCSS(direction, id, length) {
   var $parent = $('#' + id);
   var $span = $parent.find('span');

    /** RESET CSS PROPERTIES */
    if (direction === 'down') {
        // RESET FOR BIG COUNTER
        if (id === 'prog_01w') { 
            if (length < 15) {
                //14
                $span.css({'zoom':'0.50'});
                if (length < 12) {
                    //11
                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.60'});
                    if (length < 11) {
                        //10
                        $span.css({'zoom':'0.68'});
                        if (length < 10) {
                            //9
                            $span.css({'zoom':'0.75'});
                            if (length < 9) {
                               //8
                                $span.css({'zoom':'0.80'});
                                if (length < 8) {
                                    //7
                                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.9'});
                                    if (length < 7 ) {
                                       //6
                                        $span.css({'zoom':'1.0'});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }  
            }
        } else {
            // RESET FOR SMALL COUNTERS
            if (length < 12) {
                //11
                $parent.css('margin-top', '-40px');    
                $span.css({'zoom':'0.55'});
                if (length < 10) {
                    //9
                    $parent.css('margin-top', '-40px');
                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.60'});
                    if (length < 8) {
                        //7
                        $parent.css('margin-top','-20px');
                        $span.css({'zoom':'0.80'});   
                        if (length < 7) {
                            //6
                            $parent.css('margin-top','-10px');
                            $span.css({'zoom':'0.9'});
                            if (length < 5) {
                                //5
                                $parent.css('margin-top', '0px');
                                $span.css({'zoom':'1.0'});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {

        /** ADD LESS ZOOM TO PROPERTIES SO THEY SHRINK AS THE NUMBER LENGTH GETS BIGGER */
        if (id === 'prog_01w') {
            // ZOOM FOR BIG COUNTER
            if (length > 6) {
                //7
                $span.css({'zoom':'0.9'});
                if (length > 7) {
                    //8
                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.80'});
                    if (length > 8) {
                        //9
                        $span.css({'zoom':'0.75'});

                        if (length > 9) {
                            //10
                            $span.css({'zoom':'0.68'});
                            if (length > 10) {
                               //11
                                $span.css({'zoom':'0.60'});
                                if (length > 12) {
                               //13
                                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.50'});
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        } else {
            // ZOOM FOR SMALL COUNTERS
            if (length > 5) {
                //6
                $parent.css('margin-top', '-10px');
                $span.css({'zoom':'0.9'});

                if (length > 6) {
                   //7
                    $parent.css('margin-top','-20px');
                    $span.css({'zoom':'0.8'});

                    if (length > 7) {
                        //8
                        $parent.css('margin-top','-40px'); 
                        $span.css({'zoom':'0.6'});

                        if (length > 8) {
                           //9
                            $parent.css('margin-top','-40px');
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is another example of me using jQuery to update CSS. Here I am manually specifying each property value based on array length. I'm doing this so I can make a directory listing vertically responsive. I'd love to clean up this code and do it "dynamically" using some sort of algorithm.

```
            $('#col1').html(col1_html);
        $('#col2').html(col2_html);
        console.log('length', length);
        if (length === 1) {
            //only one to show, so put it in the directory instead of in the column then apply justify-content:space-around and set tenant width to 50%
            $('#col1').html('');
            $('#directory').html(col1_html);
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '80px 0 80px 0', 'width': '50%'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '70px 0 70px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'170px 0 160px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 160px 88px', 'font-size': '82px'});
            $('#directory').css({'padding-bottom':'160px','border-bottom':'3px solid #FFF','justify-content':'space-around'});  

        } else if (length === 2) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '80px 0 80px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0 0 0 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'170px 0 140px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 80px 88px', 'font-size': '82px'});
            $('#directory').css({'padding-bottom':'110px','border-bottom':'3px solid #FFF'});   
        } else if (length === 3) {

        } else if (length === 4) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '55px 0 55px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'100px 0 100px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 50px 88px', 'font-size': '82px'});
            $('#directory').css({'padding-bottom':'50px','border-bottom':'3px solid #FFF'});        
        } else if (length === 5) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '45px 0 45px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '40px 0 40px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'100px 0 80px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 80px 88px', 'font-size': '75px'});
            $('#directory').css({'padding-bottom':'80px','border-bottom':'3px solid #FFF'});            

        } else if (length === 6) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '40px 0 40px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'100px 0 80px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '75px'});
            $('#directory').css({'padding-bottom':'60px','border-bottom':'3px solid #FFF'});        

        } else if (length === 7) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '40px 0 40px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': ' 0 0 35px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'100px 0 80px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '75px'});
        } else if (length === 8) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '40px 0 40px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': ' 0 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'100px 0 80px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '75px'});          
        } else if (length === 9) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '25px 0 25px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 60px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});   
        } else if (length === 10) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '25px 0 25px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 60px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});               
        } else if (length === 11) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '25px 0 25px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 60px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 60px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});       
        } else if (length === 12) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '15px 0 15px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0x 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 50px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 50px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});               
        } else if (length === 13) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '15px 0 15px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0x 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 50px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 50px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});           
        } else if (length === 14) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '15px 0 15px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0x 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'90px 0 50px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 50px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});   
        } else if (length === 15) {

        } else if (length === 16) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '12px 0 12px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'70px 0 65px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 65px 88px', 'font-size': '72px'});               
        } else if (length === 17) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '10px 0 10px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 0px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'70px 0 45px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 55px 88px'});
        } else if (length >= 18) {
            $('.tenant').css({'padding': '9px 0 9px 0'});
            $('.occupant').css({'padding': '0px 0 5px 0'});
            $('.header').css({'padding':'70px 0 45px 0', 'margin': '0 88px 45px 88px'});
        }

        $('#col1 .tenant .occupant').css('padding-left','50px');
        $('#col2 .tenant .occupant').css('padding-left','150px');
        if (length > 1) {
            $('#col1').css({'border-right':'3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'});         
        }
        $('#col1 .tenant .suiteNumber').css({'padding-right':'100px'});
        $('#col2 .tenant .tenantName').css({'padding-left':'100px'});
```

Comment: If it's working the question might be more appropriate http://codereview.stackexchange.com/